# Cannot Run Oracle Stored Procedure From SSIS (VS 2019)

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, stored-procedures, ssis

I have an SSIS Package and in the Control Flow, I am trying to add a simple Execute SQL Task which I was hoping would run a stored procedure in Oracle. I looked on a few Forums and it appeared all I needed to do was add the Execute SQL Task to the Control Flow, select the OLE DB connection to our Oracle Database, add the statement to be run (i.e. `BEGIN EXT_AGRESSO; END;`), however I get the below error when I execute the task;

> Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "BEGIN UNITE.EXT_AGRESSO;END;" failed with the following error: "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'UNITE.EXT_AGRESSO' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
> Task failed: Execute SQL Task>

There aren't any parameters involved as this should be a simple execute however I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is fine but that procedure either does not exist, or you do not have permissions to run it, eg

```
SQL> begin  non_existent_proc; end;
  2  /
begin  non_existent_proc; end;
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PLS-00201: identifier 'NON_EXISTENT_PROC' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

In your case, check to make sure that the procedure is owned by UNITE and that you can execute it from (say) SQLPlus or SQLcl.

Comment: thank you so much. I granted Debug and Execute grants to the Stored Procedure on the Oracle Database and that's done the job. Thank you so much for helping me resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I granted Debug and Execute grants to the Stored Procedure on the Oracle Database and that's done the job. Thank you so much for helping me resolve this. Thanks to Connor McDonald for providing the useful answer :)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)